# Don't write to a channel until something happens

Tags: go

I currently have something like this

```
type Foo struct {
    rpChan        chan<- *Data
}

func (s *Foo) Work() {
    ......
    for event := range watch.ResultChan() {
        s.rpChan <- &sr
        ...........
        ...........
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else I am pulling data from that channel (rpChan) like this

```
func (r *Bar) process() {
    for t := range r.reqChan {
          //How do I Pause writing more stuff to this channel ? It has just been unblocked
          r.processEvent(t)
          //Un-Pause writing more stuff to this channel - Now send me the next thing.  
    }
}
```

My question is what would be the best way to tell the channel to stop writing more stuff to it until `ProcessEvent` is completed ? Since the `process` method just pulled something from `r.reqChan`, I do not want Foo Work() to write more data to the `rpChan` channel until `processEvent` is completed. The only thought that I have is introducing another channel that gets set when  `r.processEvent(t)`
is completed and then `process` would read from that channel to continue. Is there a better approach to this ? Perhaps a IPC queue ?

Comment: You don't "tell a channel" to do something. You write code that does the "something". But the way you've phrased the question, [milfoil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74296766/1256452) is the obvious correct response. Since that's not what you want, you must have something in mind that you have not told us about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [specification says](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Channel_types) *If the capacity is zero or absent, the channel is unbuffered and communication succeeds only when both a sender and receiver are ready.*

Make `r.reqChan` an unbuffered channel to ensure that a send to `r.reqChan` does not complete while the receiving goroutine executes `r.processEvent(t)`.

A goroutine can only do one thing at a time. If the receiving goroutine is executing `r.processEvent(t)`, then the receiving goroutine is not executing the receive operation implicit in `range`. It follows that a send does not complete while the receiving goroutine executes `r.processEvent(t)`.

Comment: This is NOT correct as soon as data is read from an unbuffered channel at that point it is capable of sending more. Can you please specify a source

Comment: @Rajeshwar Answer updated to include a source.